# How to speed up Fallout 4 loading time

Tags: fallout-4

I have a very fast PC (intel i7 6 core 3.4ghz / all disks are SSD 500MB/s 16GB ddr4 ram). But still, compared to Fallout 3, loading times are very long, when I open door, or use fast travel, I need to wait about 10 seconds, reading the message with some hints, that I wouldn't normally even notice in Fallout 3.

I thought it might be the speed of PC, but apparently, when running task manager simultaneously, I can see that CPU is constantly on 2% usage only, disk usage on 0%, ram is almost free and swap disabled. I don't see anything that would be utilized by the game and that made me think that this delay while loading some different place is here on purpose, so that you actually have enough time to read that tip you can see on loading screen.

I don't need to read these tips, is there any way to force the game to load the map as soon as it's possible? It's extremely annoying!

Comment: I know, but still it makes me feel like this delay is actually implemented in game code, and not caused by hardware not being fast enough. If it was related to hardware, there should be something highly utilized (disk?) while loading a map etc. But it's not.

Comment: There is no artificial delay in Fallout 4. Proof: Load any save game, wait for it to finish loading, then load the same file again. You'll notice the loading will happen almost instantly the second time; the game doesn't need to load any additional assets this time, since you neither moved nor did anything.

Comment: What made you think someone wasted time making an artificial delay?  Who would bother wasting time to do that?

Comment: @Nelson: so that you can read the hint on loading screen. You need about 10 seconds to do that at least. I tried loading the same game 2 times in a row, and despite second load might be faster, it was still about 10 seconds for it to load. If it really is loading stuff from disk, why it's utilization is 0%? The disk is literally sleeping, so is CPU. If it's not artificial delay, what's the game doing during that time?

Comment: The comparison with Fallout 3 isn't because I would expect both games load same fast, but in Fallout 3 you also have these loading hints, but on modern PC it's impossible to read them, because load happens in less than 1 second. You just can't read the loading tip in such a short time. So my point is, maybe they tried to fix it by employing this delay which /maybe/ could be disabled somewhere resulting in game loading much faster.

Comment: The only way there would be to speed up loading time would be to precache more assets in RAM, but that would make the game startup much longer, and the game developer would have to enable this. IMO not much you can do.

Comment: I guess the content is packed on disk and decompression is done on the fly as the task manager indicates 25% CPU (rly, _with only one core?!_) and about 1-5MiB/s from HDD. Even if the files are cached by the system (they seem to be not, as I have  only 8GiB "free/cached" and 13GiB "really free".

Comment: I highly recommend using a software like PrimoCache which will cache data to RAM and SSD (if available). This has speed up my loading times 10 times to normal and cache hit ratio after playing 30mins is 70%.It's not free but it has a 60 days trial period. http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/primo-cache/download.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have noticed this as well, and I have (more or less) proof:
Try to uncap frame rate and enter a new area. The loading time will be significantly lower. As OP says, when capped to 60fps, the loading screen (and its animation) will be much slower and wait so you have time to read the tips. Uncapped, it's almost impossible to read.

The reason for this is because the game speed is related directly to frame rate in this engine, which means going 120fps will double effective game speed. Since the loading screen itself is a very simple animation, it can reach 240+ fps easily, resulting in lower loading times.

Of course, the the same is also true for regular gameplay: NOT capping the game to 60fps will sometimes suddenly make the game speed up and make certain mini-games (like the lockpicking one) a lot more difficult. It's a shame we can't have both, but it seems we're stuck with either unnecessarily long loading times, or sped-up gameplay.

Hopefully, someone will mod this out as soon as possible.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to how to uncap frame rate? That would improve your already great answer.

Comment: Find Fallout4Prefs.ini in the folder \Documents\My Games\Fallout4. Change iPresentInterval=1 to 0. Just be aware that it's gonna cause some weird stuff in-game.

Comment: I had meant adding it to the answer, since comments can sometimes be transient on Stack Exchange. But thank you!

Comment: Wow, I am surprised that in 2015 someone created a game engine that binds the game speed to frame rate. That is something that very old dos games had problem with and why turbo button was invented :P thanks though, on other hand my FPS is usually around 40-50 (ultra graphics) and game doesn't really seem to be slower, so maybe the problems with game speed are only if it's actually higher than 60, but not lower.

Answer (score 30):

It's a well known issue related to poor coding.

The solution is to install a mod, such as [great acceleration of loading times](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/8758) or [load accelerator](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10283).

What's happening is that loading is somehow tied to your framerate, and the framerate is limited to 60 FPS. You could unlock the framerate to fix this issue, but the game's physics engine does very poorly with framerates that are too high.

The mod in question therefore unlocks your framerate during loading screens, and resets it to 60 FPS after loading has concluded. Lowering your graphics settings may further improve your loading times. Fortunately, there's not much happening on the loading screen, so lowering your graphics may not be necessary in most cases.

---

On my PC, the Commonwealth used to take over a minute to load. With the mod installed and working (check your FPS during loading screens), loading times were reduced to only tens of seconds (~200 - 300 FPS).

Comment: I don't know much about modding, and I have some very serious trust issues with installing things on my computer from randos on the internet :-) Is there a way for me to verify what exactly these mods are doing before I install them?

Comment: @WesSayeed, I'm afraid I don't know how to verify them. You could try and unlock the game's framerate without any mods (https://gameranx.com/features/id/31580/article/fallout-4-guide-how-to-unlock-framerate-to-over-60fps/), though it *could* potentially break physics in the game somehow.

Comment: @WesSayeed Mods from the Nexus tend to be very safe, as they're vetted by the rather large Nexus mods community! There's a popular following to modding Bethesda games in particular, so I would imagine this mod is pretty safe along with the others. The mod also has ~8K downloads, and the mods don't tend to be executables, rather actual modifications to the game's files.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf although I agree this situation is pretty safe, I just wanted to add that creating a mod with no exe files that acts as malware is quite possible, because even though the game files themselves aren't executables, they are being executed by the game itself, especially in the context of DLLs for example. Also there are plenty of attacks that target images files and PDFs and other non-executables, so I'd argue against using "does it have an executable" as a means by itself to determine the safety of a file. But, again, nexus has been very safe in my experience.

Comment: @Nolonar "it could potentially break physics in the game somehow" Fallout 4 has the same engine as Fallout 76, and it was discovered that the PC's movement speed was related to FPS pretty quickly. It's entirely plausible that it might affect the physics of other objects the same way.

Comment: @WesSayeed I don't know much about modding for fallout either, but I looked at this "mod" and it appears to be a simple configuration file change. You can inspect it yourself, but I can't imagine a meaningful danger coming out of this as the configuration file is not a code, but is processed by the game hence leaving limited possibilities for malicious surprises.

Comment: Holy shit... loading is tied to _frame rate?_ Bethesda is even worse at this than I thought...

Comment: [Load Accelerator](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10283) (6k endorsements, not 300) no key pressing; it's automatic. Possibly perception bias, but you wait a little bit (an audio glitch is a good point) then press tab, some mouse buttons, w/e. Use in conjunction with [Empty Loading Screens](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/40376) - 'some MBs' after the 'glitch' spin that thing you can't see around a little bit (you'll hear it); makes the cpu choke and spit it out.

Comment: The time scale and the refresh rate are both tied to the game engine. Alter either of those manually at your own risk.